Tensorflow TimeDistributed Wrapped Model Load/Save
Following the tutorial on Tensorflow here,
once the following model has been trained:
tensorflow version: 2.17.0
Input Shape: (None, 16, 224, 224, 3)
Which is (BATCH_SIZE, SEQUENCE, 224, 224,3)
net = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top = False)
net.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(scale=255),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(net),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling3D()
])


What i need assistance with is, how exactly would i save a model built with this architecture?
I tried eg. model.save('model.keras'), which saves the model but the moment i try: loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.keras') 
i get the following error:
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling TimeDistributed.call().

Cannot convert '16' to a shape.

Arguments received by TimeDistributed.call():
  • args=('<KerasTensor shape=(None, 16, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_2462>',)
  • kwargs={'mask': 'None'}


Also Tried different Ways of Saving/Loading the model:
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model.weights.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")

# load json and create model
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("model.weights.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Update:
Managed to get it working by using the following:
model.export('model')
and then importing it using:
loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load('model')
and then using
y = loaded_model .serve(np.expand_dims(sample_video, axis = 0))
